# Trouble with add attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I have a trouble with adding new attribute. So, it's my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <attributes_new>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </attributes_new>
    </modules>
    <resources>
        <attributes_new_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>attributes_new</module>
            </setup>
        </attributes_new_setup>
    </resources>
</config>
```

my folder location: [image]

And my code, where I add my attributes.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: p.kushnerevich
 * Date: 19.12.17
 * Time: 14.30
 */
$installer = $this;

$productAttributesSetup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$installer->startSetup();

$setId=1;

$productAttributesSetup->addAttributeSet('catalog_product', 'NewAttributeSet');

$groups = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_group')
    ->getResourceCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_group_name','Clothing')
    ->setSortOrder()
    ->load();

$attributeCodes = array();
$numberGroupOnPage=0;

foreach ($groups as $group) {
    $groupName          = $group->getAttributeGroupName();
    $groupId            = $group->getAttributeGroupId();
    $productAttributesSetup->addAttributeGroup('catalog_product', 'NewAttributeSet',$groupName,$numberGroupOnPage++);
    $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
        ->setAttributeGroupFilter($group->getId())
        ->addVisibleFilter()
        ->checkConfigurableProducts()
        ->load();
    $numberAttributeOnPage=0;
    if ($attributes->getSize() > 0) {
        foreach ($attributes->getItems() as $attribute) {
            $attributeName=$attribute->getAttributeCode();;
            $productAttributesSetup->addAttributeToGroup('catalog_product','NewAttributeSet',$groupName,$attributeName,$numberAttributeOnPage++);
        }
    }

}
$installer->endSetup();
```

I think, that my error in config.xml.

Comment: Please add any errors that you encounter. Please add what you expect to happen and what instead is happening.

Answer (score 2):

The Module declaration should be in capitalise `<Attributes_New>` and not `<attributes_new>`

**config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Attributes_New>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Attributes_New>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <attributes_new>
                <class>Attributes_New_Helper</class>
            </attributes_new>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <attributes_new_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Attributes_New</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </attributes_new_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: You're welcome, so it works now ?

Comment: yes, it was very stupid mistake. Again thank u so much :)

Answer (score 0):

If your code to add your new attribute is in the mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php file, so you have to change your config.xml's version like that :

```
<attributes_new>
    <version>0.1.1</version>
</attributes_new>
```